# Problem with Mkdir Runtime Error 76 path not found

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a folder with the variables I am retrieved from a word table. I have 3 variables, value2, value3, and value4. Value2 is "Jonhattan", value3 is "Smith Sun", and value4 is "123546". I created a name for the folder as a combination of 3 variables.

When I try to make a directory with these 3 names, it gives me

> Runtime Error 76

but it allows me to create the only variable1. I think the problem might be the way I retrieve those 3 values.

```
   value2 = value1(1)

value3 = value1(2) & " " & Left(value1(3), Len(value1(3)) - 1)

value4 = Left(ThirdTable.Rows(11).Cells(2).Range.text,Len(ThirdTable.Rows(11).Cells(2).Range.text) - 1)

myPath = ActiveDocument.FullName
CurrentFolder = ActiveDocument.Path & "\"
FileName = value2 & "," & value3
xfullpath = CurrentFolder & FileName

MkDir xfullpath here
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you cannot include a comma in a filename.

Comment: Include a `MsgBox xFullpath` before the `MkDir` to see what it is.

Comment: @BraX The strange thing is, when i assigned constant values to those variables, code creates the directory even with the Comma. Value2="Jonhattan", value3=" Smith Sun", and Value4="123546". But my variables are dynamic and not sure how i will convert SPLIT string back to constants.

Comment: I would avoid using `CurrentFolder` and instead just use `xfullpath = ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & FileName` - that may simplify things... and look closely at what the msgbox says to make sure the path is valid.

Comment: @BraX. Msgbox exactly says what i want to create, but mkdir gives error 76. The Path is valid and as i said when i tried with constant variables, not the ones from word table, works perfect. :/

Comment: If you are using `MkDir` then you want to specify ONLY the path/folder and NOT include the filename.

Comment: i called it Filename, but it actually consists the folder name i want to create. there is no file extension on the Filename. Same code works perfectly with on excel but word gives me trouble now.

Comment: Excel VBA and Word VBA work the same, so carefully check your code.

Comment: not for me probably. i just used the same code and worked on excel, but word been fussy at the moment.

Comment: @RALF Unlike Excel table, Word table cell text contain 2 invisible characters at extreme right (i.e. ASCII 7 and 13). If you are collecting text from table cells, take only `Left(......,  Len(....) -2 )` instead of  `Left(......,  Len(....) -1 )`

Comment: @Ahmed AU thanks Ahmed. i found it when i was trying at work last night. yes thats correct -2 instead of -1 solved my problem. But thank you very much, appreciated for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Cause of issue

MS Word table cell text ends with two invisible characters to indicate end of cell:

```
ASCII 7 - Bell
ASCII 13 - Carriage Return
```

## Solution

You should take it into account by reading all, except last two characters. In your code you should modify below lines:

```vb
value3 = value1(2) & " " & Left(value1(3), Len(value1(3)) - 1)
value4 = Left(ThirdTable.Rows(11).Cells(2).Range.text,Len(ThirdTable.Rows(11).Cells(2).Range.text) - 1)
```

To below lines:

```vb
value3 = value1(2) & " " & Left(value1(3), Len(value1(3)) - 2)
value4 = Left(ThirdTable.Rows(11).Cells(2).Range.text,Len(ThirdTable.Rows(11).Cells(2).Range.text) - 2)
```